# Connect to external API to send SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms, sendsmsactivity

Is there any way to connect external API to send SMS from Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to do this from within a journey, you could create a custom activity, that handles the calls to the external SMS-API from it's backend. This would be done within the `/activity/execute`-route.

Information on how to build custom activities can be found in the following Marketing Cloud documentation articles:

- [Create Custom Activities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)
- [Example REST Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/example-rest-activity.htm)

**Example for basic architecture:**
Furthermore you can check out a custom split activity, that I created to see a [working example of a custom journey builder activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit). However you need to change it to be a REST-activity rather than a RESTDECISION-activity. But in my opinion basic concepts like the postmonger-events, user interface and how the backend is built could be helpful for you.

Comment: Neither the question nor the answer are off topic. SFMC mobile products are tempting to circumvent. They suck. This is a perfectly valid solution to a legitimate question.